# Asp.net Jwt token validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

ASP.NET Core 2.x has a really nice way to add Bearer Authentication using JWT tokens. The following code is the minimum requirement to make things work.

```
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://issuer.com",
        ValidateLifetime = true,
    }
});
```

I understand the anatomy of a JWT `header.payload.signature` but in case we are using an Asymmetric algorithm, we need to validate the signature and for that we need to get the public keys from this url: `issuer + .well-known/jwks.json`.

So, is the middleware "magically" fetching the public keys and validating the signature? Also, is the middleware caching the public keys to avoid fetching the public keys in every validation?

Comment: Have you looked at `TokenValidationParameters` [IssuerSigningKey property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.issuersigningkey?view=azure-dotnet)?

Comment: Well, I know that property and also the `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` my question is about the public keys caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConfigurationManager` object is responsible for retrieving, refreshing and caching the configuration metadata required to validate JWTs, such as the issuer and signing keys . Middleware will retire the metadata and cahche when the first time authentication begins , see source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/b6d8c96a98c9e5673cd10162616ed98799c60d88/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions.cs#L29) .

Comment: Thank you! What happens when the token provider rotates the public keys?

Comment: @MarcoTalento ,middleware will refresh the configuration for exceptions that may be caused by key rollovers  , see [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/b6d8c96a98c9e5673cd10162616ed98799c60d88/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L116)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I forgot that asp.net core is open source now! Unfortunately, there is no similar mechanism in .net framework 4.x provided by the framework.